# Could not load the file or assembly {ASSEMBLY-DETAILS} The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, vsto, filenotfoundexception

Recieving this error in a VSTO project. The program flows like this:

WordAddIn (VSTO project) >> Ribbon btn click >> Capture content of doc >> All went ok? >> Call Office.Forms.frmOfficeAddIn.Initialise() >> Call same form's mbSignOn() function

A FileNotFoundException occurs at the final stage, mbSignOn(), because it cannot find the library ADODBHELPER. According to the FusionLog, it seems to be looking for the dll in the WordAddIn vsto project, even though the project is referenced and used exclusively in a seperate project containing frmOfficeAddIn.

This same code works on my standard dev machine (64bit Win7). The trouble is occurring on a new dev machine I'm trying to get up and running (32bit Win7). Exception details, fusion log included below. Any help appreciated.

Exception Msg:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'ADODBHELPER, Version=6.0.8.19015, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"ADODBHELPER, Version=6.0.8.19015, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}

Stack Trace:

> at OfficeCaptureAddIn.frmOfficeAddIn.mbSignon()
>      at OfficeCaptureAddIn.frmOfficeAddIn.Initialise(Dictionary`2 dictFiles) in C:\SOURCECONTROL\dotNET\Office\Forms\frmOfficeAddIn.vb:line 45

FusionLog:

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = ADODBHELPER, Version=6.0.8.19015, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/SOURCECONTROL/dotNET/dotNET/WordAddIn/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

## Calling assembly : OfficeCaptureAddIn, Version=5.0.6073.19015, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\SOURCECONTROL\dotNET\dotNET\WordAddIn\bin\Debug\WordAddIn.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/SOURCECONTROL/dotNET/WordAddIn/bin/Debug/ADODBHELPER.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/SOURCECONTROL/dotNET/WordAddIn/bin/Debug/ADODBHELPER/ADODBHELPER.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/SOURCECONTROL/dotNET/WordAddIn/bin/Debug/ADODBHELPER.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/SOURCECONTROL/dotNET/WordAddIn/bin/Debug/ADODBHELPER/ADODBHELPER.EXE.